# Handle max 5 request per second?

Tags: java, spring

I have this code

```
  int concurrentCalls = 5;
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(concurrentCalls);
    AtomicLong time = new AtomicLong(0);

    try {
        for (Incident incidentOrChangeReq : listIncidentsOrChangeRequests) {
            enforceRateLimit();

            semaphore.acquire();
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                Object listDetailsObject = new Object();
                try {
                    final StopWatch outageDetailsTime = new StopWatch();
                    outageDetailsTime.start();

                    listDetailsObject = integrationClient.getOutageDetails(accountId, incidentOrChangeReq.getNumber());

                    outageDetailsTime.stop();

                    time.addAndGet(outageDetailsTime.getTotalTimeMillis());
                    log.error("outage details time: " + outageDetailsTime.getTotalTimeMillis());

                    final StopWatch setJsonTime = new StopWatch();
                    setJsonTime.start();
                    String detailsListJSON = ow.writeValueAsString(listDetailsObject);
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(detailsListJSON);

                    setValues(typeOfExport, jsonObject1, mapper, incidentOrChangeReq);
                    setJsonTime.stop();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error(e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    semaphore.release(); // Release the permit
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("InterruptedException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

What i want to achive is to call max 5 request per second, that is this part of code

```
  listDetailsObject = integrationClient.getOutageDetails(accountId, incidentOrChangeReq.getNumber());
```

and if sum of those 5 request is smaller than 1second to wait for that difference and than continue to next 5 request and so on.. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use Computable Future and Push 5 tasks each second using a Thread sleep in the main Thread.

Comment: Maybe, take a look to the `RateLimiter` object in the Guava library.